# i get and error from the browser: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

Tags: reactjs, forms, input, undefined, react-forms

I created a reusable input component in React with a dynamic class name such that on mouse hover the label will move out on the input field. I ran the code several times and it worked well, but suddenly it throws an error which I cannot figure out. This is my code:

```js
const FormInput = ({ label, ...otherProps }) => {
  return (
    <div className='group'>
      <input className='form-input' {...otherProps} />
      {label && (
        <label className={`${otherProps.value.length ? 'shrink' : ''} form-input-label`}>{label}</label>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
export default FormInput;
```

Comment: `otherProps.value` is probably `undefined`.

Comment: you can try `className={\`${otherProps?.value?.length ? 'shrink': ''\`}`. Sometimes when the otherProps are not resolved synchronously it can be possible that in the initial render, the variable is undefined. However, this solution will only work if you are sure that the otherProps are going to get resolved to a defined value from the parent component.